# Override module-sales-rule

Tags: checkout, sales

I'm trying to override module-sales-rule and it's not working I have successfully overwritten module-checkout. Here is what I have done.

I have copied all files from

`vender/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/`

to

`app/design/frontend/<vender>/theme/Magento_Sales_Rule/`

And have tried just adding the file I want to edit and with no luck.

I have run the following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

The command below throws an error

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Could not parse theme static file '/app/design/frontend/<vender>/theme/Magento_Sales_Rule/web/js/view/cart/totals/discount.js
```

Any ideas would help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like to overwrite module-sales-rule use Magento_SalesRule not Magento_Sales_Rule if anyone else is interested.

Comment: Hi, how can i override /var/www/html/dg/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Subselect.php